# Why is AngularJs a lot slower on iPad (vs desktop)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ipad, angular-ui-router

Whenever a page goes through an actual digest (with around only 600 watchers) the page load is about 6 times slower on ipad vs desktop (calculated by using console.time).

My current research:

- There is the intentional delay upon touching a button on iPad, that was fixed by using fastclick.
- I don't think its due to touch event as a tried on a touch screen with a mouse and the speed is about the same (when using mouse vs touching).
- Both desktop/ipad seem to be caching responses as you'd expect.
- By using developer tools it seems it has to do with something in digest, I couldn't find any add ons for safari (doesn't seem to exist) to break down timing in the digest.
- No problems on safari on desktop, or any other browser for that matter. Problem exists on multiple iPads.
- I've heard including jQuery slows it down and tried removing it but same problem exists

I'm not looking for general ways to increase performance but to fix/troubleshoot this .. bug? I've ran out of ideas, please help! :D

Edit:
I'm not using ionic, it's web based.

Comment: Why did this question get a negative vote?

Comment: Too many issues, too little code. You didn't even bother to tell us which iPad you were testing on. It's impossible for us to reproduce your problem with the question written this way. See [ask]

Comment: haha, you want me to post my entire app on here? Try any iPad with 1000+ watchers and you'll see it. I wish this post (without the negativity) was on stack overflow before we started. We may have to rewrite our application, and I'm really disappointed AngularJs didn't mention this. I'll be going into a store in a second to check other iPads to see if something will work but this is an issue with iPads (Javascript slowness).

Comment: No, we don't want you to post your entire app. We *do* want you to make a better effort to narrow down the problem to a [mcve] -- something we can actually help you solve. As it stands, your question is unanswerable by anyone but yourself since we lack the ability to recreate your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I found the issue, its not angularjs but Javascript. On iPads javascript is much slower (http://ajaxian.com/archives/ipad-javascript-shockingly-slow).

Confirmed by running Google Octane (https://developers.google.com/octane/). Desktop Safari Browser: 29942, iPad Safari Browser: 6795.

This kinda sucks.

EDIT:

Tested out various iPads:

Android (Using Chrome v49 (latest)):

- Galaxy tab S2 9.7: Octane Score 6901
- Galaxy Tab A 8.0: Octane Score 2650
- Galaxy Tab A 9.7: Octane Score 2886
- Samsung Galaxy Tab: Octane Score 2622

Chromebook (Using Chrome v49 (latest)):

- Lenovo Chromebook: Octane Score 8641
- Ases 2in1 Touch-Screen: Octane Score 7378
- HP Chromebook: Octane Score 8688

Ipad (Safari)

- Ipad Pro: Octane Score 20,632
- Ipad Air 2: Octane Score 10,601
- Ipad Mini 4: Octane Score 9,902

As Blazemonger pointed out the article is old but the point is still true, javascript is slower on iPads/Tablets, particularly on android.

We found with about only 300 watchers the magical octane number is 10,000 (of course there are many other variables but to give someone an idea). So as long as you don't need your application to be fast on all iPads/Tablets you can rely on AngularJs (Although I guess the real problem is just heavy javascript).

Comment: That Ajaxian article is almost six years old as of this writing.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using ionic, you make a precompiled app in a web, so you have one more layer to process(iOs-> browser -> webApp) , in the pc the browser is just one layer( browser -> webApp)

WebApp is slower than native apps.

Comment: I'm not using ionic, its all web based